# Create uniformity in lowercasing and uppercasing values

Tags: r

I have several columns that have values that are a mix of lowercase, uppercase, etc., letters. I'd like for the first letter of a word to be uppercase and the letters after to be lowercase.

An example of what I'd like:

```
phoenix        Phoenix
Little rock    Little Rock
AUGUSTA        Augusta
```

Comment: Another option `stringi::stri_trans_totitle(x)`

Comment: ..or `tools::toTitleCase(x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str_to_title` from the `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)

str_to_title(c("phoenix", "Little rock", "AUGUSTA"))
# [1] "Phoenix"     "Little Rock" "Augusta"
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `gsub`

```
gsub("\\b([a-z])", "\\U\\1", tolower(v1), perl = TRUE)
#[1] "Phoenix"     "Little Rock" "Augusta"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("phoenix", "Little rock", "AUGUSTA")
```